# Why Google ComputeEngine Rest API does not return qualified values for Instance Templates which are necessary to create Instances

Tags: java, google-compute-engine

I'm trying to create VMs on Google ComputeEngine, using Java api and sourcing data from instance templates.
Getting instance template is simple:

```java
try (InstanceTemplateClient instanceClient = InstanceTemplateClient.create()) {
            ProjectGlobalInstanceTemplateName globalInstanceTemplateName = ProjectGlobalInstanceTemplateName.of(instanceTemplateName, projectName);
            instanceTemplate = instanceClient.getInstanceTemplate(globalInstanceTemplateName);
        }
```

however there is no obvious way how to use instanceTemplate then, without specifying all properties separately, e.g.

```java
try (InstanceClient instanceClient = InstanceClient.create()) {
            ProjectZoneName zone = ProjectZoneName.of(projectName, zoneName);
            InstanceProperties instanceProperties = instanceTemplate.getProperties();

            Instance instanceResource = Instance.newBuilder()
                    .setShieldedInstanceConfig(instanceProperties.getShieldedInstanceConfig())
                    .setCanIpForward(instanceProperties.getCanIpForward())
...
```

but what is even worse, instanceTemplate has not qualified values for several propeties (e.g. machineType, diskType), so I need to update them (I get error otherwise - "Invalid value for field 'resource.disks[0].initializeParams.diskType': 'pd-standard'. The URL is malformed.)

```java
.setMachineType("zones/" + zoneName + "/machineTypes/" + instanceProperties.getMachineType())
```

Manually qualifying those parameters feels very fragile. Is there better way to do it? I'm using google-cloud-compute 0.99.0-alpha

Answer (score 1):

Creating a single instance based on an instance template is a bit "special" in the API. The instance template is passed as an [optional query string parameter (sourceInstanceTemplate)](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/instances/insert) in addition to the normal instance resource definition in the POST body.

As far as I can see, the Java client library does not currently model this concept, so you're left with either the workaround you already have or - alternatively - you could perform this API request yourself as it is relatively simple as long as you do not customize a lot of values for your instance. [An API call example for this approach can be found here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/create-vm-from-instance-template#creating_a_vm_instance_from_an_instance_template).

Comment: Very cool, thank you. Do you know off hand how do i authorize when making raw post call, if im running as page in gae?

Comment: Actually, would it maybe be possible to use `InstanceClient.create(InstanceSettings settings)` and when building the `InstanceSettings`, use `insertInstanceSettings().setSourceInstanceTemplate(..)` ?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't see setSourceInstanceTemplate on the insertInstanceSettings. I see that InsertInstanceHttpRequest has getSourceInstanceTemplate but i have not figured out how to set it. I'm using google-cloud-compute 0.99

Comment: ok, not tested yet, but this looks very promising: InsertInstanceHttpRequest request =
                    InsertInstanceHttpRequest.newBuilder()
                            .setZone(zone == null ? null : zone.toString())
                            .setInstanceResource(instanceResource)
                            .setSourceInstanceTemplate("template")
                            .build();
            
            Operation response = instanceClient.insertInstance(request);